# SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed with Unable to find certificate chain

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, ssrs-2016

I am trying to Connect SSRS ReportServer with HTTPS Protocol from Java Client it's giving **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Unable to find certificate chain**
But I have added the certificate in Java Keystore, It the keystore the certificate is showing with the defined alias name.
But Same SSRS Request call is working with HTTP Protocol.
**Note:** We are using a wildcard certificate  from Go-Daddy for secure communication

Answer (score 0):

When you got your certificate, there should have been a p7b (possibly) included with it.

Essentially, when GoDaddy issues a certificate, they are not issued from the root directly.

Most likely you have one issued from an intermediate authority.

You can get the intermediate certificates at https://ssl-ccp.godaddy.com/repository?origin=CALLISTO

The certificate chain needs to be appended to the actual certificate and imported on the ***server***.

The PEM file containing the cert being imported should look like:

```
<actual certificate>
<intermediate certificate>
[<intermediate certificate> ...]
```

After that you shouldn't have a need to do anything else on the client.

*EDIT*

After re-reading my answer, I realized there may be a little bit of vagueness with regard to the process. So in efforts to bring this more full cycle here we go.

1. Generate keypair / self-signed certificate as say PKCS#12 container.
2. Create PKCS#10 certificate signing request to send to GoDaddy of above certificate.
3. GoDaddy returns signed X.509 Certificate (typically with instructions on how to install it).
4. Taking the certificate (assuming PEM format) and concatenate the issuance chain from https://ssl-ccp.godaddy.com/repository?origin=CALLISTO and import that back into the PKCS#12 from step 1.
5. Assign the PKCS#12 as the TLS certificate store on the SSRS server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the certificate is added to 'Java Truststore' and not Keystore (although both have .jks extension).
Have a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablqw/index.html

> Keystore file, keystore.jks, contains the Application Server’s certificate, including its private key
>
> Truststore file, cacerts.jks, contains the Application Server’s trusted certificates

Answer (score -1):

Stuck for months with the above error(PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert). Nothing on Stack Overflow helped. Swapped Oracle Java SE for OpenJDK Azul Zulu. Bam! Problem gone.